# Не пробрасываются порты docker-compose

Tags: golang, docker, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  database-test:
  database-dev:
  database-prod:

services:
  #Sample
  chat-service: &chat-service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/dockerfiles/golang/Dockerfile
      target: golang
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/go/src
  chat-database: &chat-database
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    image: postgres:14.1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DATABASE_DB}_test", "-U", "${DATABASE_USER}_test" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 2s
      retries: 10
    env_file:
      - .env
  #Test
  chat-service-test:
    <<: *chat-service
    container_name: chat-database-test
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=chat-database-test
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_test
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_test
      - DATABASE_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/dockerfiles/golang/Dockerfile
      target: golang_test
    networks:
      - database-test
    depends_on:
      chat-database-test:
        condition: service_healthy
  chat-database-test:
    <<: *chat-database
    container_name: chat-database-test
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_test
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_test
    volumes:
      - chat-database-test:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    networks:
      - database-test
  #dev
  chat-service-dev:
    <<: *chat-service
    container_name: chat-database-dev
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=chat-database-dev
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_dev
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_dev
      - DATABASE_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/dockerfiles/golang/Dockerfile
      target: golang_dev
    networks:
      - database-dev
    depends_on:
      chat-database-dev:
        condition: service_healthy
  chat-database-dev:
    <<: *chat-database
    container_name: chat-database-dev
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_dev
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_dev
    volumes:
      - chat-database-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    networks:
      - database-dev
  #prod
  chat-service-prod:
    <<: *chat-service
    container_name: chat-database-prod
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=chat-database-prod
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_prod
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_prod
      - DATABASE_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/dockerfiles/golang/Dockerfile
      target: golang_prod
    networks:
      - database-prod
    depends_on:
      chat-database-prod:
        condition: service_healthy
  chat-database-prod:
    <<: *chat-database
    container_name: chat-database-prod
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}_prod
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}_prod
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_DB}_prod
    volumes:
      - chat-database-prod:/var/lib/postgresql/data:delegated
    networks:
      - database-prod


volumes:
  chat-database-test: { }
  chat-database-dev: { }
  chat-database-prod: { }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Base image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang:1.18-bullseye AS golang
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}
RUN getent passwd $UID || (groupadd --gid $GID user && useradd --uid $UID --gid user --shell /bin/bash --create-home user)
USER $UID
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src
COPY . $GOPATH/src
ENV GO111MODULE="on" \
    GOOS=linux

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang AS golang_test
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src
ENTRYPOINT go test -v ./...

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Development image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang AS golang_dev
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT go run cmd/main.go

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM golang AS golang_build
RUN go build -mod=vendor -o $GOPATH/bin/main $GOPATH/src/cmd/main.go
RUN chmod +x $GOPATH/bin/main


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Production image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM alpine:3.7 as golang_prod
COPY --from=golang_build /go/bin/ ./
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

**cmd/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "URL.Path = %q\n", r.URL.Path)
    log.Print("URL.Path5 = %q\n", r.URL.Path)
}
```

поднимаю
`docker-compose run --rm chat-service-dev`

делаю запрос

```
GET http://localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json
```

ответ

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:3000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

ОС: Win 11
Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать `docker-compose up chat-service-dev`

А если уж используешь `docker-compose run`, то надо использовать спец. аргумент, чтобы порты открылись `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports chat-service-dev`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

> --service-ports       Run command with the service's ports enabled and mapped
> to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри контейнера, чтобы прослушать внешний порт используй IP 0.0.0.0. Должно помочь, пиши если не поможет.

```
func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", doX)
   if err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:3000", nil); err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
}
```